# useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy at runtime. Managed DirectX

Tags: c#, runtime, directx, app-config, managed

I am using Managed DirectX with C# and don't want to have to use a App.Config in my application. This is a working app config example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Here is the post I am following

http://reedcopsey.com/2011/09/15/setting-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-at-runtime/

Some how  A different runtime is  already bound to the legacy CLR version 2 activation policy. Why is this? I know that this code is from 2011 has something changed with the way mixed mode assembly loading works? Is there still a way to set useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy without a App.Config?

Here is the code that should work but does not.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestWindow
{
   public static class RuntimePolicyHelper
   {

   public static bool LegacyV2RuntimeEnabledSuccessfully { get; private set; }

    static RuntimePolicyHelper()
    {
        var clrRuntimeInfo =
                (ICLRRuntimeInfo)RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeInterfaceAsObject(
                Guid.Empty,
                typeof(ICLRRuntimeInfo).GUID);
        try
        {
            clrRuntimeInfo.BindAsLegacyV2Runtime();
            LegacyV2RuntimeEnabledSuccessfully = true;
        }
        catch (COMException)
        {
            // This occurs with an HRESULT meaning 
            // "A different runtime was already bound to the legacy CLR version 2 activation policy."
            LegacyV2RuntimeEnabledSuccessfully = false;
        }
    }

    [ComImport]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    [Guid("BD39D1D2-BA2F-486A-89B0-B4B0CB466891")]
    private interface ICLRRuntimeInfo
    {
        void xGetVersionString();
        void xGetRuntimeDirectory();
        void xIsLoaded();
        void xIsLoadable();
        void xLoadErrorString();
        void xLoadLibrary();
        void xGetProcAddress();
        void xGetInterface();
        void xSetDefaultStartupFlags();
        void xGetDefaultStartupFlags();

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void BindAsLegacyV2Runtime();
    }

}
internal static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main()
    {
        if (RuntimePolicyHelper.LegacyV2RuntimeEnabledSuccessfully)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new TestWindow());
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy failed", "Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: That is not going to help you *at all*.  Only a custom CLR host is going to let you run with a .config file, C++ and a steep learning curve required.

Comment: I don't want or need a .config file the whole reason behind this post is so that I can get rid of the .config I have now. I just want to set useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy without it. As shown here http://reedcopsey.com/2011/09/15/setting-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-at-runtime/

Comment: That blog post doesn't show you how to call it, it shows you how to check if the app was started with a .config file.  It depends on the exception being thrown if it wasn't.  Very ugly, and doesn't solve your problem at all since your program can only work if the .config file is used.  Using a .NET 1.1 DirectX wrapper that's been obsolete for 10 years doesn't win any prizes either.

Comment: You are right about that. But the app is already using legacy DirectX9. I guess the move to SharpDX and DX11 is going to have to happen.